# MongoDB $or operation behaviors

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

In my Node.js application, I am querying the MongoDB database, using multiple `$in` expressions inside the `$or` operation, like the following:

```js
const sectionIds = [1,2,3,4,5];
const classIds = [1,2,3,4];
const classItemIds = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

Record.find({
  $or: [
    { sectionId: { $in: sectionIds } },
    { classId: { $in: classIds } },
    { classItemId: { $in: classItemIds } }
  ]
});
```

I am concerned about its behavior and performance. Does it start checking expressions inside the `$or` array in the order specified? Does it stop checking when the upper expression is successful? For example, if `sectionId` meets the condition, will it continue checking for `classId` and `classItemId`, or it stops?

Comment: Have you tried adding an explain() after your query?

Comment: I imagine MongoDB's $or works the same way an OR operator works in any other language. Namely, it stops checking after the first truthy condition.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? See [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html).

Comment: @prasad_ Thank you, I have got what I was looking for from the docs.